# How to create wpf effects that extend outside the controls bounds?

Tags: wpf, hlsl, pixel-shader

I've been fiddling with shazzam to create all kinds of cool PS effects but I still don't understand how an effect can affect areas outside the element its applied on, like the original blur or dropshadow effects for an exmaple. Can anybody elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the shaders are applied to a texture with the same sithe as the source control. But you can change this size by setting PaddingLeft, PaddingRight, PaddingBottom, PaddingTop properties on your ShaderEffect.

When your padding is > 0 both the input and output textures will be increased by this padding. So basically you won't have to make any uv transformations to take padding in account.